# Compare files SIDE by SIDE using win batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am doing the following, but have two issues with this (win 2003):

1. Output includes first and last line that is matching :-(
2. Output is not side by side

Can these two issues be solved? Suggestiongs (I tried /nnn and /lb options)

**SCRIPT:**

```
:bof
    ::Swith off echo - the @ switch off echo for this line
    @echo off  
    :: Clear screen
    cls 
    :: Keep Locals contained to this batch file           
    setlocal       

    :: Set the two files and check that they exist
    set fileA=X:\tst\pfsrc\alex.txt
    set fileB=X:\tst\cbsrc\alex.txt
    if not exist "%fileA%" echo %fileA% not found & goto :end
    if not exist "%fileB%" echo %fileB% not found & goto :end

    :: del .old file rename previous output file to .old
    rem if exist X:\tst\cbsrc\resultPF1.old del X:\tst\cbsrc\resultPF1.old
    rem if exist X:\tst\cbsrc\resultPF1.txt rename X:\tst\cbsrc\resultPF1.txt *.old

    :: compare files
    FC /c /l /n /w %fileA% %fileB% 

:end
```

***1st INPUT FILE:***

```
new line
line1
line2
line3
line4
insert new line
and another new line
line5
line6
line7
and a line here
line8
line9
line10
what is this line?
line11
```

***2nd INPUT FILE:***

```
new line
alex
hart
was
here
line5
line6
line7
line8
line here
line9
line10
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
Comparing files X:\TST\PFSRC\alex.txt and X:\TST\CBSRC\ALEX.TXT
***** X:\TST\PFSRC\alex.txt
    1:  new line
    2:  line1
    3:  line2
    4:  line3
    5:  line4
    6:  insert new line
    7:  and another new line
    8:  line5
***** X:\TST\CBSRC\ALEX.TXT
    1:  new line
    2:  alex
    3:  hart
    4:  was
    5:  here
    6:  line5
*****

***** X:\TST\PFSRC\alex.txt
   10:  line7
   11:  and a line here
   12:  line8
   13:  line9
***** X:\TST\CBSRC\ALEX.TXT
    8:  line7
    9:  line8
   10:  line here
   11:  line9
*****

***** X:\TST\PFSRC\alex.txt
   15:  what is this line?
   16:  line11
***** X:\TST\CBSRC\ALEX.TXT
*****
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FC` command always show differences as sets of lines listed one after the other; there is no way to show the differences side by side. You may get `FC` output and process it in a Batch program so the differences be displayed side by side, but you must realize that this program should identify different particular cases in order to correctly show two sections side by side.

Some time ago I wrote such a program; I called it "FComp.bat" and you may download it [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3968). For example:

```
C:\> FComp.bat /C /L /N /W 1stInputFile.txt 2ndInputFile.txt
Comparing files 1stInputFile.txt and 2NDINPUTFILE.TXT

==============================  SECTION MODIFIED  =============================

    1:  new line                       |    1:  new line
    2:  line1                          |    2:  alex
    3:  line2                          |    3:  hart
    4:  line3                          |    4:  was
    5:  line4                          |    5:  here
    6:  insert new line                |    6:  line5
    7:  and another new line
    8:  line5

==============================  SECTION MODIFIED  =============================

   10:  line7                          |    8:  line7
   11:  and a line here                |    9:  line8
   12:  line8                          |   10:  line here
   13:  line9                          |   11:  line9

OLD SECTION DELETED AT END OF FILE  ===========================================

-   15:  what is this line?
-   16:  line11
```

Comment: +1 I really like this solution! Very nicely done, and I think it will not be hard to further amend it to either exclude first and last matching lines or to at least line them up better.